# canPlayType always returning maybe? Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, video

I'm using canPlayType() to determine if a browser can play a specific video format before I load it into the video tag, but when I test it, it returns "maybe" for all video formats. My code is below. Am I missing something?

```
canItPlay1 = document.getElementById('intro_video').canPlayType('video/webm');
canItPlay2 = document.getElementById('intro_video').canPlayType('video/ogg');
canItPlay3 = document.getElementById('intro_video').canPlayType('video/mp4');

alert("Can play type? "+canItPlay1+canItPlay2+canItPlay3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use codecs, along with type while alling canPlayType() as canPlayType('video/webm',codecs ="mp4a.40.5"). 
If you include codecs, then only you will get "probably" as the result.